# Is Spring security login form equivalent to Httpclient post method?

Tags: forms, authentication, spring-security, httpclient

**SPRING SECURITY LOGIN FORM** this is login.jsp i.e. http://localhost:8082/Spring-MVC/login.jsp

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>
```

**JSP Code equivalent to above post form method,**

```
<%  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8082/SpringMVC/j_spring_security_check");
            postMethod.addParameter("j_username", "mkyong");
            postMethod.addParameter("j_password", "123456");
            try {
                httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
            } catch (HttpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (postMethod.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                String resp = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
            } else {
                 //...postMethod.getStatusLine();
            }
            %>
```

**Actually, I'm thinking that both result the same but in the second case by using post method it is not redirecting me to home page. i want to make above form submission automated using  httpclient code. Please, help me out in this**

Answer (score 0):

You are not propagating the session from the JSP in the post request so, you are sending a throw-away request to the authentication filter

Comment: can you give me a sample code for the propagating the session using httpclient?

Comment: even in the form we are just sending the throw-away request I guess?